# Routing in MVC3 for Content Management

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a content management system written in .NET 4.0 and uses MVC3. 
My client wants her URL's to be SEO friendly, and gave me a list, but they want all of the dynamically generated pages (content pages) all be 1st level URL's.

Example:
www.example.com/dynamiclygenerated

When I add to the route table the url would be something like

routes.MapRoute( "ContentPages", "{*pageRoute}", new { controller = "Pages", action ="ContentPage"}, new[] { "Example namespaces" });

The problem I am encountering is that it qualifies every URL and sends it to the Pages controller. 
What I need is a way to route URL's if the first level is in the database.

1ST time poster, sorry if this question is too vague. Any help or thoughts would be appreciated! Thank you for your time.

UPDATE: To clarify, I had a Route that qualified all incoming URL's and passed them to my Page controller. I needed a way to filter the URL of the request, to see if it needed a content page, or a store page, or even the default page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was I had a route that qualified everything (basically an additional default route)
I had to constrain it to only accept values that matched links in my content pages repository.

I did this by adding a custom Route Constraint, and added logic in the Match method to pull all entity's from my content pages repository that matched the current URL request. If it did not have one, then return false. This allowed pages that needed to go to the next controller to bypass my 1st level catch all route.

Answer (score -1):

Do not fully understand your question, but if you have the following:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Then create an action link such as:

```
@Html.ActionLink("name", "Action","Controller", new { id = ValueToPass }, null)
```

The above would give you what you require